# Voice memos - Recordings.db not updated on iOS 7.1.2

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

On my freshly hard reset iPhone 4 (iOS 7.1.2), when I record a voice memo it does not show up in the Recordings.db database.

The database itself is present and well formatted but the ZRECORDING table  stays empty. The recording and playback work perfectly well though.

Tested on another iPhone 4 running the same iOS version, it works as expected (ie a new entry is created for each new voice memo with timestamp, duration and path)...

Am I missing something here or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

OK I've figured it out, thanks to [this page](http://sandersonforensics.com/forum/content.php?197-Forensic-examination-of-SQLite-Write-Ahead-Log-%28WAL%29-files).

If I understand correctly, the Recordings.db file is just the "structure" of the SQLite database. The transactions are stored in another file called "Recordings.db-wal".

Quote : "*WAL files are a form of cache whereby data that is written to an SQLite db is first written to the WAL file (when this is enabled) and then at a later time (known as a checkpoint) the SQLite data is written into the main database*".

So in order to view the data, Recordings.db **and** Recordings.db-wal needs to be in the same directory before opening Recordings.db with a SQLite DB viewer.